# Input from an istream to a char* pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++20, istream

I am reading Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++" (second edition). On page 660-661, the writers define a function as follows:

```cpp
istream& read_word(istream& is, char* buffer, int max)
    // read at most max-1 characters from is into buffer
{
    is.width(max);    // read at most max-1 characters in the next >>
    is >> buffer;     // read whitespace-terminated word,
                      // add zero after the last character read into buffer
    return is;
}
```

Later in `int main()`, the function is called as `read_word(cin,s,max);` where `cin` is `std::cin`, `max` is an `int`, and `s` is a `char` array of size `max`.

I don't understand how `is >> buffer;` works. In particular, that line gives an error when I tried to run the code:

> C2679 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'char *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

There is no user-defined `operator>>` or further explanation on that line (except the comment) in the book.

I wonder if we can use things like `is >> buffer;` in any meaningful way? If so, how does it work? Or is this an error in the book?

---

**Update**: I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I found that the code runs successfully with C++14/17, but not with C++20. The results are similar for clang and gcc.

Comment: Code looks good to me. https://godbolt.org/z/hjz8YjcKe If you add a [mre] and the complete and unadulterated build error message from the output tab maybe someone will see something I missed.

Comment: Ha! I didn't even think to try C++ 20. Didn't expect anyone using Visual Studio would be using it. Last I checked, it defaulted (yes defaulted. Not defecated, you stupid spell checker) to C++14, so I defaulted to 14. Maybe I'm being compiler racist, but I'm not as bad as the spell checker which clearly seems to think Visual studio is caca.

Answer (score 22):

The `std::basic_istream::operator >>` overload that takes a `char*` argument ([overload #2 in this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2)) was removed in C++20. This change will, no doubt, break huge amounts of existing code, *including examples given by Bjarne Stroustrup himself!*

The C++20 replacement, taking a `char (&s)[N]` argument instead, seems (to me, at least) far less accessible. One way to adapt to this change is to rewrite the `read_word` function as a template, when you would no longer require the explicit `max` argument and the call to `is.width()`:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
std::istream& read_word(std::istream& is, char (&buffer)[N])
{
    is >> buffer;
    return is;
}
```

However, as mentioned in [Alan Birtles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72961516/10871073), you should really be moving away from raw `char[]` arrays and start using `std::string`, instead.

Comment: How much of that existing code was correctly setting width to prevent buffer overflows though? I'm not aware of a single time I've used this overload in my professional career either?

Comment: @Alan Agreed. The 'old' operator *is* dangerous and I can sort of understand why the Standard Committee removed it. (Possibly the C++ 'analogue' of the horrible `gets` function?)

Comment: Worth noting that The most recent edition of Principles and Practices is pretty old now. About time for a new rev that covers C++17 and 20 (and maybe 23).

Comment: What is this madness? We can suddenly do breaking changes in C++ to fix archaic constructs?

Comment: @Quimby there have been a few breaking changes in new c++ revisions, e.g the removal of `auto_ptr`

Comment: @Quimby I'm pretty sure that there are other changes made at C++20 that break some existing code. Probably also true for other Standard releases, too.

Comment: Found some code a few weeks back that went nuclear over the C++11 `auto` change.

Answer (score 9):

The [stream operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) taking a raw char pointer has been replaced with one taking a fixed sized char array in c++20. The simplest solution is to use `std::string` instead.

To use an array your code would be something like:

```
template <size_t N>
istream& read_word(istream& is, char (&buffer)[N], int max)
    // read at most max-1 characters from is into buffer
{
    is.width(max);    // read at most max-1 characters in the next >>
    is >> buffer;     // read whitespace-terminated word,
                      // add zero after the last character read into buffer
    return is;
}
```

Note that this will now read at most `N-1` characters, if `N` and `max` are the same then you can omit `max` and the `width` call.

Comment: Should `max` also be of type `size_t`?

Comment: @Chris `streamsize` would be the most appropriate https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width though strangely `setw` takes an `int` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw